# How do I make my website scalable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, resolution

I am creating a website in HTML and CSS. I want it to look the same (i.e. have the same proportions and sizes) regardless of what resolution the display is or what size the window is. I could do this by giving my `<div>` elements `width:100%;` but this makes it so that when the window is stretched, the content of the `<div>` also stretches or scrunches up. I could do this by giving specific pixel values but this would make it either too big or too small on screens with different resolutions - I've tested this by changing the resolution on my computer and testing. What do I do to make it look the same on all displays in all browsers?

Comment: This question is too broad, make a first web page and post that, and then ask how to solve issues or unwanted behaior that page might have

Comment: One of the easiest ways is to use bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding your question, I think this is what you're looking for:

`    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />    `

Comment: If you want to make it responsive you will need to use your own media queries or to redesign your site using bootstrap for example.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I am having the same issue on my website. https://oneenterprisestech.github.io The CSS is being changed, so it looks really poor right now.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution, is the quality of the image. I personaly do not know how to change the quality. But i know how to fit the image to what ever screen your using which is what i think the problem is.

If say you are programming and your screen looks like this

[image]

but then you need to figure out how this looks like on mobile?

so you press ctrl + shift + i(Only works on chrome and chromium) and you get a screen that looks like this:

[[image]

Now you can edit the website to look the way you want it to. and in the middle left you can click that and see how your app looks when sized to different phones and tablets. And say you want it on a specific sized screen you can edit the pixels and make a custom.

But then lets say that when you press ctrl + shift + i and you get it out of proportions like this

[image]

Then your problem is a missing line of code. To  solve this all that you need is this:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```